# LDAP command to delete all users attached to a group

Tags: ldap

Is there any LDAP command to delete all users attached to a specific group.  Assume there are user1,user2,user3 assigned to group G1 . I want to delete all the users attached to group G1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are not *attached* to a group, entries are *members* of a group. To delete all entries that are members 
of a group, execute a search that will return all of distinguished names that are members of the group:

- make the base object of the search the distinguished name of the group
- use `(&)` or `(objectClass=*)` for the filter. Some directory servers, for example Sun DSEE in certain
  versions fail to properly parse the filter `(&)`
- use `base` for the search scope
- request the attribute type whose values are the distinguished names of the members of the groups. This varies,
  but could be something like `uniqueMember`

Then, transmit a delete request for each distinguished name returned from the above search.
Some servers support `referential integrity`, if so, the members of the group will be deleted
at the same time as the entries are deleted.

#### See also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)